# TensorFlow get updates computed by optimizer

Tags: tensorflow

In `tf`, the optimizer class only has two function:

- `compute_gradients`
- `apply_gradients`

where `apply_gradients` returns an op that performs the update `w <- w + Δw` via a `tf.assign_add` function.

However I need direct access to the `Δw` itself. (or `w' = w+Δw`). I know that the optimizer adds nodes to the computational graph which compute this `Δw` for each variable. How can I access them? Or do I have to re-implement the optimizer myself?

The reason is that I need to compute gradients `dw'/dw`, as I am working on something related to gradient based hyperparameter optimization (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01785)

Answer (score 0):

The "delta" applied to each variable is not accessible through any common method or name. In fact, looking a bit into the source it seems rather difficult extract, as it varies from one optimizer to the other.

What you can do, at least, is to compute the differences between variable values and their updates. For example it could work like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Setup example model
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
    w = tf.Variable([[1., 2.]], tf.float32)
    pred = x @ w
    loss = (tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(pred, y))
            / tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.float32))
    # Record variable values before training step
    # (tf.identity should work here but it does not so we use
    # a trivial add operation to enforce the control dependency)
    w_old = w + 0
    # Train after having recorded variable values
    with tf.control_dependencies([w_old]):
        train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
    # Compute deltas after training
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
        w_delta = w.read_value() - w_old
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Test
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        print(sess.run(w))
        # [[1. 2.]]
        _, w_delta_val = sess.run(
            [train_op, w_delta],
            feed_dict={x: [[1.], [2.]], y: [[3., 4], [5., 6.]]})
        print(w_delta_val)
        # [[0.79999995 0.5999999 ]]
        print(sess.run(w))
        # [[1.8 2.6]]
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. However, this is not usable to me, as I do not simply just need the value, but also graph depency. I will update the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

To get the updated `w'`, you get just print the `w` directly after you have executed `optimizer.apply_gradients()`. The `w` at present is the `w'`.

Now, if you want to acquire the gradient of `w`, just do the operation of `w'-w`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the gradients are scaled by the learning rate!